# Login page as default first page in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, apollo-client

**Description**

i'm working on reactjs and apollo client project. i'm also developing login feature. loginmutation is working but it must type manually on browser like "localhost:3000/login".

my spec is :

ReactJS v16

React Router v5

**Problem**

I'm trying to redirect url path "/" to page "/login" in this code :

```
// mapping route
const routing = (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/reset-password' component={ResetPassword} />
        <Route exact path='/new-password/:token' component={NewPassword} />
        <Route path='/' component={App} />
        <Redirect exact from='/' to="/login"/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </ApolloProvider>
)
```

But when i'm login and it's successfull, it always redirect back to login again. it maybe conflict in this code :

```
 <Route path='/' component={App} />
 <Redirect exact from='/' to="/login"/>
```

and here's also mutation code for login :

```
const client = useApolloClient();

const[login, { loading, error }] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(data.login.token).replace(/"/g, ''));
        client.cache.writeData({ data: { isLoggedIn:true } });
        props.history.push('/');
    },
    onError: (err) => {
        handleShowErrorModal();
    }
})
```

**Question**
How to make login as default page in web app and login successfuly direct to dashboard (in this case is App component) not redirect again to login?

Any help will be appreciated, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can check the user if the user is logged in or not, If the user is logged in keep the user on the `'/'` route else, navigate the user to `'/login'`.

```
 <Route path='/' component={App} />
 <Redirect exact from='/' to="/login"/>
```

In your code here, you are trying to use '/' for both the main page and the login page. I suggest you use `/login` for the login page.

You can use this at the top of your routing in the App.js file:

```
<Route element={<Navigate to="login" />} path="/" />
<Route element={<Login />} path="/login" />
```

This will make login the default page and in the login component, you can do something like this that will redirect the user back to the home page.

```
if(isLoggedIn){
   navigate('/');
}
```